# Initialising Javascript based component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I'm pretty new in react and I keep stumbling on the problem of initialisation of javascript content. Lets take the example of `Materialse Carousal`, here

```
<div className="slider">
    <ul className="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
        <div className="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 className="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
        <div className="caption left-align">
          <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 className="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
        <div className="caption right-align">
          <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 className="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
        <div className="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 className="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

HTML content is quite simple, but where to exactly initialise or what is the right way to make it work in React.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
    });
```

This is the carousal initialisation code. I tried placing at the end of the same jsx file where I defined the slider, but I keep getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function`. Also tried initialising in `componentDidMount` but no success.

Can someone point me the right way of initialising content in React.

Similar issue with some other component that require initialisation..like select.

Similarly for social login (Like Facebook, LinkedIn etc), I am suppose to initialise user by passing API between some script tag. I get that working by placing the script tags in my entry HTML file, but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: Without seeing more of how the project is set up, all I can guess at is that the Materialize js is either not being loaded at all, or is not completing loading by the time your React code is being initialized.  You are on the right track by using `componentDidMount`, though.  FB has [an example of using Bootstrap's JS components in React Components](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/examples/jquery-bootstrap) in their code base which you might have seen.

Comment: Actually I'm bundling two js file. One with all the dependencies like material.js etc using gulp and another with all the jsx code and imports using browserify. And in my html, dependencies are loaded before the other js file...

Comment: The problem is that it is unable to get slider() function... I dont know what is it I'm doing wrong..

Comment: Do you have a github or other such place you can post the whole project?  Or failing that, can you post the project setup in your question?  (gulpfile, package.json, small outline of your project's file tree)  The former will be the most helpful since I'll be able to see things that you might not even know to consider yet.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using bitbucket for that. I'll see if I can do that...

Comment: Bitbucket has public repositories, so that will work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103778/discussion-between-moid-mohd-and-joseph-sikorski).